# Combining multiple compound mysql statements

Tags: mysql

First I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM members
    WHERE username IN (
      SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends 
          WHERE (friend1 = 'user' AND friend2 <> 'user') 
          UNION
      SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends
          WHERE (friend2 = 'user' AND friend1 <> 'user')                                       
    )
```

The above code works perfectly. It returns all rows from the 'members' table that match a given users friends list - which is created by searching the table list_friends for the given user and grabbing the friend name from either column friend1 or friend2.

Like I say, it works flawlessly.

Next I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT username,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sites WHERE username = 'user') 
+ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banners WHERE username = 'user') 
+ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stream_updates WHERE username = 'user')
    AS cnt from members WHERE username = 'user'
```

This will combine the counts of the given rows and output the total sum of all COUNT as a column cnt.

I want to combine these two statements so I can get a result that returns friend, cnt.

Example output would be very simple:

```
   username    |  cnt
 ----------------------
  a friend     |  6525
  diff friend  |   983
  yet again    |  3485
```

I could easily run this in two php loops, first get the names of the friends from the first query, and then use a foreach and run the second query in the loop of the first query, I am just wondering if there is a better way, or a way to otherwise combine the statements into one to get the above output.

Comment: Do you want the count from the first query or all the rows?

Comment: the first query returns the "friends". I then want each friend to be run through the second query toget that friend "cnt".

Comment: to make this really clear we are getting a "friends list" for a given user, then each user of that friends list we are counting the total "actions" they have performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT username,
       ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sites s WHERE s.username = f.username) +
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banners b WHERE b.username = f.username) +
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stream_updates su WHERE su.username = f.username)
       ) as cnt
FROM (SELECT friend2 as username
      FROM list_friends 
      WHERE friend1 = 'user' AND friend2 <> 'user'
      UNION
      SELECT friend1 as username
      FROM list_friends
      WHERE friend2 = 'user' AND friend1 <> 'user'                                     
    ) f;
```

Note:  You don't need the `members` table here.  You have the `username` from the other tables.

Comment: you are missing a + on the end of the third line, but this is exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you.

Comment: @Bruce . . . I'm glad this helped.  It is a complicated query.  Cheers.